# How to get ListViewItem from a virtual mode ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can i get the `ListViewItem` of a `ListView` that is in virtual mode?

i *would* call:

```
 //Get ListViewItem corresponding to index 37

 var e = new RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs(37);
 listView.RetrieveVirtualItem(sender, e);

 return e.Item;
```

except that Andreas Helberg decided i should not be allowed to do that.

How can i get the `ListViewItem`, corresponding to an index, of a virtual mode ListView?

Comment: I suppose you would like to mantion Anders Hejlsberg. Don't think he has any desicional/architectual impact on `Windows Forms` technology.

Comment: @Tigran It's a C# language peculiarity; the code in this case wants to call the event handler - which has been forbidden.

Comment: do you saw this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.virtualmode.aspx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to create a class and inherit from whatever class you're using which inherits from `ListView` (I'm assuming this because if you were using the `ListView` class directly, then you would probably have access to the underlying cache and the mechanisms to get the item at a particular index would be manifest), create a public wrapper function, call the protected `OnRetrieveVirtualItem` function with the parameter you specified in your example code and the return the `.Item` from there, so

```
RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs args = new RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs(37);
this.OnRetrieveVirtualItem(args);
return args.Item;
```